# Google analytics fake pageview without java support

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a website that have over 5000 visits a day. The actual problem is we ask to the user to complete a form and want to track in analytics how many user have complete the form successfully.

Our form is a ajax post. I try different thing.

Try to put an event on the "success" method of the ajax call. The accuracy is very bad

Try to put a normal page view in the "completed" page. But when the user are on mobile "page view" are fire a second time when the user "re open" the page to navigate to another page. So the tracking is not accurate

I try to put a # and remove it when the "fake page view" `ga('send', 'pageview', [page], [fieldsObject]);` as been done. It's working fine to avoid tracking "double" cell user. But some user are not track!

My question is.

When i look my report, a lot of user did not have "java support". Is it possible that the "no java support" has an impact on the google analytic tracking?

Comment: Don't think Java support will impact the analytics. Seems just like common data being collected and displayed - I imagine there would be similar data for Flash or other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Google Analytics uses JavaScript to communicate with the server, not Java.

Java and JavaScript have about as much in common as Car and Carpet.

Comment: I know that javascript and java are two thing completly differrent. But i was asking myself if it was possible that Google Analytics API was using or calling "java applet" in an obscur .js file to perform there tracking.

Comment: @CédricBoivin I _really_ doubt it. It would be bad on so many levels starting with security, usability and reliability. It'd be pretty much useless. It's more likely that a lot of the users are web crawlers or have extensions that prevent tracking or might be blocked by firewalls or other networks or more.

Comment: @CédricBoivin — As the answer says, they do not use Java.